# Link_to not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

Alright, either I need to go to bed or change careers. An incredibly simple `link_to` is failing and I just can't see where.

```
#routes.rb
resources :wikis

#view.html.haml
= link_to @wiki.title, wiki_path(@wiki)
```

Errors with:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"wikis", :id=>#<Wiki id: 10, created_by_id: 1, ...
```

Now I'm not doing anything crazy like overriding the primary key; anything.

Here's the associated Wikis#show route in `rake routes`:

```
wiki GET    /wikis/:id(.:format)                            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"wikis"}
```

Comment: can you post an output of `rake routes | grep wikis` ?

Comment: is it the view for index action?

Answer (score 2):

you can try

`<%= link_to @wiki.title, @wiki %>`

Answer (score 1):

does it works: `wiki_path(@wiki.id)` ?

Comment: This works, but the way I posted above should as well. I have a bunch of existing code I'm not wanting to update unnecessarily either.

Comment: I suppose you're not overloading `to_param` on Wiki ? try checking the return value of @wiki.to_param

Comment: Looking through the source, :to_param will work regardless of what it returns, so long as it's unique. The issue was that the key I was using in :to_param was nil.

Comment: ^^ ok, and one quick reminder for all of us: to_param should return a string in order helpers to work properly, so be careful when using non-string field to convert them inside the to_param method.